# Remove a row from Html table based on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a html table

```
<TABLE id="dlStdFeature" Width="300" Runat="server" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="0">
  <TR>
    <TD id="stdfeaturetd" vAlign="top" width="350" runat="server"></TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
```

I am dynamically adding values to it as :

```
function AddToTable(tblID, value)
{
    var $jAdd = jQuery.noConflict();

    var row= $jAdd("<tr/>").attr("className","lineHeight");
    var cell = $jAdd("<td/>").attr({"align" : "center","width" : "3%"});
    var cell1 = $jAdd("<td/>").html("<b>* </b>" + value);
    row.append(cell);
    row.append(cell1);
    $jAdd(tblID).append(row);
}
```

Now I want a function to remove a row from this table if the value matches..as

```
function RemoveFromTable(tblID, VALUE)
{
   If(row value = VALUE)
   {
     remove this row
   }
}
```

**Here VALUE is TEXT ..which needs to be matched..If exists need to remove that row,,**

Comment: Hello. What is the value of a line for you? Would you say the id or the title ?

Comment: I also would not recommend removing the row (manipulating DOM is heavy). Maybe just hiding it will be enough?

Comment: VALUE is TEXT, which needs to be matched

Comment: how you are calling RemoveFromTable()

Comment: calling from a javascript function

Comment: yaar....on any click event or anything...??

Comment: a drop down change event...need to manipulate values from  html table based on the drop down selection

Comment: can you tell us what it values return..??

Comment: return value = string text..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

```
function RemoveFromTable(tblID, VALUE){
   $("#"+tblID).find("td:contains('"+VALUE+"')").closest('tr').remove();
}
```

hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
function RemoveFromTable(tblID, VALUE)
{
   If(row value = VALUE)
   {
      $("TR[id="+VALUE+"]").hide();  //Assumes that VALUE is the id of tr which you want to remove it
   }
}
```

You can also .**remove**() like

```
$("TR[id="+VALUE+"]").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using a ViewModel in your case. So you can dynamically bind your data to a table and conditionally format it to whatever you like. Take a look at Knockout.js: http://knockoutjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
function RemoveFromTable(tblID, VALUE){
   $(tblID).find('td').filter(function(){
     return $.trim($(this).text()) === VALUE;
   }).closest('tr').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Remove row from HTML table that doesn't contains specific text or string using jquery.**

Note: If there are only two column in HTML table, we can use "last-child" attribute to find.

```
*$(document).ready(function(){
$("#tabledata tbody .mainTR").each(function(){
    var lastTD = $(this).find("td:last-child");
    var lastTdText = lastTD.text().trim();
    if(!lastTdText.includes("DrivePilot")){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

});

Note: If there are more than two column in HTML table, we can use "nth-child(2)" attribute to find.

**Passing column index with "nth-child(column index)"**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#tabledata tbody .mainTR").each(function(){
    var lastTD = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2)");
    var lastTdText = lastTD.text().trim();
    if(!lastTdText.includes("DrivePilot")){
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

});

Note: "DrivePilot" is nothing but text or string